# Mui Datagrid height exceeds parents div when the rows are "more" than the height after MUI Datagrid 6

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

So in mui grid 5 this worked nicely. The grid should overflow in itself and create a scroolbar. Now its makes the window scroll and grow it.
Why?

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same issue recently going to v6.3.1.

It seems *immediately* wrapping your DataGrid component with a simple div with a height fixes the issue. The vertical scroll will now appear on the component itself, as it did with v5.  I already had a  component with a minHeight size that was working nicely, as you said.

```
<div style={{ height: '77vh' }}>
   <DataGrid
     .
     .
     .
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes that works nicely. But that's kinda meh. I need the parent to be a flex so it fills it's own parent which is 100vh.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
<Stack minHeight={0} height={1}>
  <DataGrid />
</Stack>
```

- import { Stack ] from '@mui/material'